# Get Website Data Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-scraping, nsurlsession

I am trying to use a `NSURLSession` to pull some data from espn, but I can't seem to get it to work. It prints only `nil`.

I've tested this method with another page on their website and it worked, but I can't get it to work with the one in the code. Here is the code in question:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2271")

if url != nil {

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        print(data)

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

            print(urlContent)
```

I've also tried changing the encoding type which didn't work either. The data it's printing looks like it's UTF 8 format, so I didn't think that would work but felt I should try.

I feel like I've run out of ideas to work.

**Edit :** Should have specified more, `print(data)` prints out what I expected, encoded data, but `print(urlContent)` prints `nil`.

Comment: Is the data printed ? What's the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified more, data prints, but when I print urlContent it only prints nil.

Comment: Can you try this ? `var urlContent = NSString(data: NSData!, encoding: Uint)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the full example that works

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2271")

if url != nil {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(data)

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as NSString!

            print(urlContent)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Looks like the right encoding here is `NSASCIIStringEncoding`not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: Ah I didn't even think of ASCII encoding! Thank you so much!

Comment: let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as String

Comment: if let url = NSURL(string: "http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2271") { ... }

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the best way to go about this but the above answers do not work in swift 3 so I used this.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2271")

    if url != nil {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print(data as Any)

            if error == nil {

                let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) as NSString!

                print(urlContent as Any)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should works like this :

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2271")

if url != nil {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(data)

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: NSData!, encoding: Uint)

            print(urlContent)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```